# Web site is slow in any webkit based browser

Tags: debugging, webkit

There's a site that uses CSS and JavaScript a lot.

The site loads fine in Firefox, almost instantly. When opening the site in any webkit-based browser (I've tried midori, arora and vimprobable2), CPU load spikes to 100% and stays like that for about 60 seconds. Then the site loads. As soon as I want to scroll the site using the mouse wheel - CPU load jumps to 100% again.

Is it possible to debug the site somehow when having it opened in a webkit-based browser and find the reason of high CPU load? Is there something like Firebug for webkit-based browser that can be used for this?

I'm sure that it doesn't happen due to DNS, because I can reproduce the issue by downloading the html pages locally and load it from there in browsers. It loads fine in Firefox, CPU load jumps to 100% in webkit-based browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebug Lite within Safari:

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite